# Inserting a (python) cell when calling Jupyter nbconvert

Tags: jupyter, nbconvert

**Is it possible to make nbconvert insert a cell prior to processing the notebook?**
Or perhaps detect when it's being run through nbconvert or web interface

*Expanding a bit on the why*:

MathJax lacks siunitx, so in order for me to see understandable math in the notebook and output better-looking units (or customize through a template) in pdf I'd like to resort to adding a command-line argument to nbconvert, using the printviewlatex extension, so that it inserts a python cell that changes the notebook behaviour to output latex instead of markdown.

I realize that there's an siunitx MathJax extension (which I failed miserably to install in jupyter), but this solution may also solve other problems.